# The notification tray at the top of Stack Exchange sites: what is it called? And are there other good examples of this?

Tags: design-patterns, feedback, notification, terminology, stackexchange

I'm trying to clean up notifications for a client site and was wondering if the notification pattern that Stack Exchange employs has a name that I can use to search for more examples.

[image: stacked-notifications]

Comment: Are you referring to the message that pops up when you earn a badge? We tend to call that the "flash", based on the same concept from Ruby on Rails, eg. http://rubypond.com/blog/useful-flash-messages-in-rails

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The terms I see the most are "message bar", "notify bar" and "notification bar".

There are tons of examples with Google using the terms above.  Below are a few.

['Notify Bar' plugin](http://www.dmitri.me/misc/notify/)

[Top Floating message box using jQuery](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/07/top-floating-message-box-using-jquery.html)

[jQuery: How to show a message bar at the top of browser window](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/447/jquery-how-to-show-a-message-bar-at-the-top-of-browser-window)

Comment: We also use "Notification Bar"

Comment: The Stack Exchange team also call it a "notification bar." See http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site:blog.stackoverflow.com+notification+bar and http://twitter.com/jzy/status/24755401237

Answer (score 9):

Within Google, we call it a Butter Bar, to disambiguate it from all the other types of notifications that might also be shown on a page.

Comment: are you referring to the full width notification bars like here at SE, or the shorter butter-coloured bars which are overlaid top-centre of the page?

Answer (score 6):

I just found a good page from Chromium project about this UI element. They call it infobar and have there quite nice guidelines, rationale and examples: http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/infobars

Answer (score 1):

IE calls it "information bar".

Answer (score 1):

As Rahul mentioned, this is called the "flash" in [Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash), [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1467/flash), [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/), [Lithium](http://www.jblotus.com/2011/08/17/adding-a-session-flash-message-to-your-site-in-lithium-php/) and [TYPO3](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.3.0/view/3/12/) at least.

Answer (score 0):

It's called banner in material design:
https://material.io/design/components/banners.html