# Is there an official name for the yellow notification bar that appears on top of browsers like chrome?

Tags: notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The notification tray at the top of Stack Exchange sites: what is it called? And are there other good examples of this?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/the-notification-tray-at-the-top-of-stack-exchange-sites-what-is-it-called-and)

I have started seeing a lot of browsers/apps start using this "notification bar" appear from the top to inform the user of certain events:
[image: notification bar]

I think Chrome even has an API that extensions can use to trigger it. Does anyone know what, if any, this is called?

Answer (score 1):

Doh, never mind: This thread answers it: It is indeed called a notification bar:

[The notification tray at the top of Stack Exchange sites: what is it called? And are there other good examples of this?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/the-notification-tray-at-the-top-of-stack-exchange-sites-what-is-it-called-and)