# What is the proper name for "notification bars" in web design?

Tags: website-design, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The notification tray at the top of Stack Exchange sites: what is it called? And are there other good examples of this?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/the-notification-tray-at-the-top-of-stack-exchange-sites-what-is-it-called-and)

Many sites these days make heavy use of large, dynamic horizontal blocks to confirm an action (“You have successfully..” ) or make the user aware that he personally should do something given his profile or funnel. Users can usually remove the block from the page by clicking an X.

What would be a good, generic name for this kind of notification block?

Comment: Duplicate. Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

See this question:

[The notification tray at the top of Stack Exchange sites: what is it called? And are there other good examples of this?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/the-notification-tray-at-the-top-of-stack-exchange-sites-what-is-it-called-and)